# Sorting an array of numbers using .sort, but I don't know why this works

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Noob question. So, I am sorting an array of numbers in ascending order, but I don't understand why this works.

```js
const sortYears = arr => {
  arr = (a, b) => {return a - b;}
}

const years = [1970, 1999, 1951, 1982, 1963, 2011, 2018, 1922];

console.log(years.sort(sortYears()));
```

What does `a - b` actually achieve? Is it not just returning another number? How is it suddenly able to sort these numbers?

Comment: It is not sudden, that's how it's supposed to work. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: If the result is zero, the items are equal, if its negative or positive determine if it's greater or lesser. That's how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of the number produced by `a - b` or `b - a` is in relation to 0:

1. `b === a` - the items' order respective to each other won't change
2. `b - a < 0` - move `a` to a lower index than `b`
3. `b - a > 0` - move `b` to a lower index than `a`

However, the `sortYears` function returns `undefined`, so it's not taken into account. Although the default sort is ascending. It created by converting the items to strings, and sorting them as strings. Supplying a compare function will ensure that they are sorted as numbers (note the placement of the number 2 using the default compare):

```js
const sortYears = () => (a, b) => a - b;

const years = [1970, 1999, 1951, 1982, 1963, 2011, 2, 2018, 1922];

console.log(years.sort(sortYears())); // with compare function
// [2,1922,1951,1963,1970,1982,1999,2011,2018]

console.log([...years].sort()); // using the default compare
// [1922,1951,1963,1970,1982,1999,2,2011,2018]
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually didn't mean to type it up that way and I edited the question. But this helps me understand why it wasn't in descending order as I originally intended.

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain why `a - b` is different than the default compare.

Answer (score 1):

Take any two years, say 1970 and 1963. `1970 - 1963` gives you a positive number. That means 1970 goes after 1963 in the list. `1963 - 1970` gives you a negative number, so 1963 goes before 1970 in the list. It's the same as this:

```
 const sortYears = arr => {
    arr = (a, b) => {
        if(a - b > 0){
            return 1
        }else if (a - b < 0){
            return -1
        }else if(a - b === 0){
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the **sort()** method sorts the values as strings in alphabetical and ascending order. To work well with numbers you need to provide a **compare function** to define an alternative sort order logic. The function should return a **negative**, **zero**, or **positive** value.

Inspecting your function:

```
const sortYears = () => (a, b) => b - a;
```

If, depending of the arguments, it returns:

- negative: the **b** value is the lower value
- positive: the **b** value is the greater value
- zero: both values are equal

Hope that helps.